# Linking a Separately Created Google Appscript to a Google Sheet Issue

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

New to appscripts here. I want to understand the linkage of an Appscript object and a google sheet.
Is there any difference between an appscript created from within the sheet - via Menu/Extensions/Appscript

as against
Creating it within the google drive home folder, via the +NEW button, where then you say - you want to create an Appscript.
IMO - there is actually no difference. But then - how does the AppScript know to which spreadsheet it is tied to?
Or fundamentally an AppScript is not tied to any sheets object per se- and you can call any googlesheet accessible to you in your drive via a created AppScript.

Comment: In this case, the script must be implemented as a library and you can use it in as many worksheets as necessary, calling this library in that worksheet!

Comment: @SidneyCardosodosSantos I don't think the OP is talking about Library scripts. I "think" they are just asking whether & what is the difference between a standalone vs "bound script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've asked about the difference(s), if any, between a `standalone` and a `container bound` script, and some aspects of scripts. I'm going to keep this fairly simple. If you need more detailed information, then please ask. Also, have a good look at [Google Apps Script overview](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview) - there's a lot of useful information there.

**Container Bound (bound)**

A `container bound` (or just `bound`) script is one which is created from a WorkSpace document, such as a Sheet, Doc, Slide, Form, etc. Many/most users will never create anything other than `bound` scripts.

Q: How does `bound` script "know" to which document is tied to?
A: Google maintains the AppsScript DashBoard (https://script.google.com/home) where the properties of every project are managed. The linkage between a script and its container (if any) is documented in that database.

**Standalone**

A `standalone` script is created without being linked to a specific document. They're typically used for a specific, specialised purposes. It's entirely possible that a typical user will never create a `standalone` script.

**What is the difference between a `standalone` Vs `bound` script.**

In functional terms, there is no difference. Both types of script access/open documents by using methods like `openById(id)` or `openByUrl(url)`, and they can use any of the methods described in the documentation. Obviously a bound script doesn't need to "open" its container though it may need to create definitions to access specific elements of the document.

`Bound` scripts can also call a [few methods that standalone scripts cannot](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound#special_methods), including:

- `getUi`
- In Sheets: `getActiveSheet`, `getActiveRange` and `getActiveCell`
- In Docs: `getCursor` and `getSelection`.

`Bound` scripts can be used to create `custom functions` as well as `custom menus`, `dialog boxes` and `sidebars`.

Users, other then the owner of a document, can have permission to `edit the document`. In this case, they also have permission to run any scripts; and, because they can access the main menu, a user can also `edit a script`. A user's ability to edit a script is "sometimes good, sometimes bad".

Comment: Would like to add that there are a few ["special methods"](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound#special_methods) such as `getUI`, `getCursor` or the `getActive` ones, that only work with container-bound scripts. To use these the script does have to "know" which file it's attached to. So if a user wants to use these methods they will have to create a bound script.